# Back-ticks within double quotes

Tags: terminal, syntax, zsh, double-quotes, backticks

```
java -jar ngdbc.jar -c "SELECT Name as Title, Desc as Description FROM `table_name` "
```

I want to add an argument with back-ticks within the query string. However when I execute it in the terminal the back-ticks get executed first and it says zsh: command not found: table_name. Any ideas on how to work around the problem ?

Comment: Work around: Don't use backticks inside double quotes, or escape them. They are supposed to be expanded. What's the purpose of having  literal backticks in a SQL statement anyway?

Comment: @user1934428 That's the required syntax for some dialects of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Backticks are subject to expansion in a double-quoted string. Either escape the backticks individually

```
java -jar ngdbc.jar \
   -c "SELECT Name as Title, Desc as Description FROM \`table_name\`"
```

or use single quotes for the entire argument

```
java -jar ngdbc.jar \
   -c 'SELECT Name as Title, Desc as Description FROM `table_name`'
```

---

In shell, backticks are an old form of command substitution. For example,

```
$ echo "Command substitution: `echo 3`"
Command substitution: 3
```

This is equivalent to the newer, nestable, more readable form `$(...)`:

```
$ echo "Command substitution: $(echo 3)"
Command substitution: 3a
```

Answer (score -1):

try to use this one

```
java -jar ngdbc.jar -c "SELECT Name as Title, Desc as Description FROM ${table_name}"
```

In bash or zsh terminal back-ticks are using to run commands.